# C# Webpage Running Client Side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to create a C# webpage such that it can do computations client side ? I need to do some heavy computation and it would be better if it used the client's hardware rather to than sending the data to the web server and processing it through there. Is this at all possible or is it disabled for security ?

Comment: if you want to use C#, use Silverlight, otherwise, write JavaScript.

Comment: Sure. Just use JavaScript. :-)

Comment: Or cross compile C# to javascript. Cross compiling isn't necessarily an easy thing: https://www.google.com/search?q=cross+compile+c%23+to+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: javascript or silverlight

Comment: Does it have to be a web page? If you want to use C# client side, you might want to consider a WPF or Windows Store app.

Comment: Also XBAP can be used to download and run c# application using a browser tab.